# How to set 3 months date range in date picker?

Tags: jquery, validation, date, datepicker

I have from date and to date here. I want to set my maxDate to 3 months depends on the from date selection. If the user select from date 01-01-2014, #to maxDate should be next 3 months based on the from date, like (01-04-2014).

```
$(function () {
    $("#from").datepicker({
        minDate: "dateToday",
        changeMonth: true,
        dateFormat: 'dd-mm-yy',

        onClose: function (selectedDate) {
            $("#to").datepicker("option", "minDate", selectedDate);
        }
    });
    $("#to").datepicker({
        minDate: "dateToday",
        changeMonth: true,
        dateFormat: 'dd-mm-yy',
        maxDate: selectedDate + "+3M", //I want to set condition like this

        onClose: function (selectedDate) {
            $("#from").datepicker("option", "maxDate", selectedDate);
        }
    });
});
```

give me some suggestion to solve my problem

Comment: Please don't tag your question with [tag:jquery-validate] when it has nothing to do with this plugin.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

[**Fiddle DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/cse_tushar/M2RS8/)

```
$(function () {
    $("#from").datepicker({
        minDate: "dateToday",
        changeMonth: true,
        dateFormat: 'dd-mm-yy',
        onClose: function (selectedDate, instance) {
            if (selectedDate != '') { //added this to fix the issue
                $("#to").datepicker("option", "minDate", selectedDate);
                var date = $.datepicker.parseDate(instance.settings.dateFormat, selectedDate, instance.settings);
                date.setMonth(date.getMonth() + 3);
                console.log(selectedDate, date);
                $("#to").datepicker("option", "minDate", selectedDate);
                $("#to").datepicker("option", "maxDate", date);
            }
        }
    });
    $("#to").datepicker({
        minDate: "dateToday",
        changeMonth: true,
        dateFormat: 'dd-mm-yy',
        onClose: function (selectedDate) {
            $("#from").datepicker("option", "maxDate", selectedDate);
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: It works on the first click... but If i click on other place in same page and again I going to click, It is not working... http://jsfiddle.net/a79EQ/1/ see it here

Comment: First click on from text box. Don't select date. Click on blank space of the same page. Then again click on from text box. The datepicker not showing

Comment: Hai , how to change the to date month selection only based on from date date change ( single month only ) . if i click march 5 as from date means and i ll choose update march 31 only in to date

Comment: Excellent!! Exactly what I needed!!

Answer (score 3):

```
$(function() {
    $( "#datepicker" ).datepicker({
        numberOfMonths: 3,
        showButtonPanel: true
    });
});
```

Here is the [Documentation](http://jqueryui.com/datepicker/#multiple-calendars)

```
$("#startDate").datepicker({
    minDate: 0,
    onSelect: function(selected) {
        var date = new Date(selected);
    date.setMonth(date.getMonth()+3);
        $("#endDate").datepicker("option","maxDate", date);
    }
});
```

Here is your resut man.... Cheers....

Comment: Enjoy +1 for Puliyankudi

Comment: @Chelladurai, Could you give me your jsfiddle demo

Comment: @CJRamki Sorry for the delay buddy. [Here](http://jsfiddle.net/5DexE/1/) is the FIDDLE