# Wordpress - Date Picker limiter

Tags: php, jquery, wordpress

I have a datepicker gdlr-hotel.js in a plugin on wordpress. I need to limit the dates to 2 months only. I have tried max date, minDate. I have tried to disable changemonth, etc... But nothing works.

```
(function($){
    "use strict";

    $.fn.gdlr_datepicker_range = function(){
        var gdlr_dfm = ($(this).attr('data-dfm'))? $(this).attr('data-dfm'): "yy-mm-dd"; 
        $(this).datepicker({

            minDate: 0,
            dateFormat : gdlr_dfm,
            numberOfMonths: [1, 2],
            beforeShowDay: function(date) {
                var date1 = $.datepicker.parseDate(gdlr_dfm, $("#gdlr-check-in").val());
                var date2 = $.datepicker.parseDate(gdlr_dfm, $("#gdlr-check-out").val());
                return [true, date1 && ((date.getTime() == date1.getTime()) || (date2 && date >= date1 && date <= date2)) ? "dp-highlight" : ""];
            },
            onSelect: function(dateText, inst) {
                var date1 = $.datepicker.parseDate(gdlr_dfm, $("#gdlr-check-in").val());
                var date2 = $.datepicker.parseDate(gdlr_dfm, $("#gdlr-check-out").val());
                if (!date1 || date2) {
                    $("#gdlr-check-in").datepicker('setDate', dateText);
                    $("#gdlr-check-out").val('');
                } else {
                    $("#gdlr-check-out").datepicker('setDate', dateText).trigger('change');
                }
            },
            closeText: objectL10n.closeText,
            currentText: objectL10n.currentText,
            monthNames: objectL10n.monthNames,
            monthNamesShort: objectL10n.monthNamesShort,
            dayNames: objectL10n.dayNames,
            dayNamesShort: objectL10n.dayNamesShort,
            dayNamesMin: objectL10n.dayNamesMin,
            firstDay: objectL10n.firstDay
        }); 
    }

    $.fn.gdlr_datepicker = function(){
        $(this).each(function(){
            if( $(this).attr('data-dfm') ){
                var current_date = new Date($(this).val());
                $(this).val($.datepicker.formatDate($(this).attr('data-dfm'), current_date));
            current_date.setMonth = (current_date.getMonth()+2)
$.fn.gdlr_datepicker.tre = current_date 
$.fn.gdlr_datepicker.maxDate = new Date(today.getFullYear(),today.getMonth() , today.getDate());
  $.fn.gdlr_datepicker.today = function() {
    $.fn.gdlr_datepicker.dt = new Date();       
            }

            $(this).datepicker({
                dateFormat : ($(this).attr('data-dfm'))? $(this).attr('data-dfm'): "yy-mm-dd",
                minDate: 0,
                altField: ($(this).attr('data-dfm'))? $(this).siblings('.gdlr-datepicker-alt'): "",
                altFormat: ($(this).attr('data-dfm'))? "yy-mm-dd": "",
                changeMonth: false,
                changeYear: false,
                onSelect: function(dateText, inst){
                    $(this).trigger('change');
                    $('#gdlr-datepicker-range').datepicker('refresh');
                },
                closeText: objectL10n.closeText,
                currentText: objectL10n.currentText,
                monthNames: objectL10n.monthNames,
                monthNamesShort: objectL10n.monthNamesShort,
                dayNames: objectL10n.dayNames,
                dayNamesShort: objectL10n.dayNamesShort,
                dayNamesMin: objectL10n.dayNamesMin,
                firstDay: objectL10n.firstDay
            });     
            // $(this).datepicker('setDate', new Date($(this).val()));
        });
    }

    $.fn.gdlr_single_booking = function(){

        var resv_bar = $(this); 
        $(this).find('.gdlr-datepicker').gdlr_datepicker(); 

        // check in date and night num change
        $(this).on('change', '#gdlr-night, #gdlr-check-in', function(){
            var check_in = resv_bar.find('#gdlr-check-in');
            var check_out = resv_bar.find('#gdlr-check-out');
            var night_num = resv_bar.find('#gdlr-night');

            if( check_in.val() ){

                var check_out_date = check_in.datepicker('getDate', '+1d'); 
                check_out_date.setDate(check_out_date.getDate() + parseInt(night_num.val()));

                check_out.datepicker('setDate', check_out_date);

                var check_out_min = check_in.datepicker('getDate', '+1d'); 
                check_out_min.setDate(check_out_min.getDate() + 1);

                check_out.datepicker('option', 'minDate', check_out_min);
            }
        });

        // check out date change
        $(this).on('change', '#gdlr-check-out', function(){
            var check_in = resv_bar.find('#gdlr-check-in').datepicker('getDate');
            var check_out = $(this).datepicker('getDate');
            var date_diff = (check_out - check_in) / 86400000; // 1000/60/60/24

            if( check_in && date_diff > 0 ){
                var night_num = resv_bar.find('#gdlr-night');
                if( night_num.children('option[value="' + date_diff + '"]').length == 0 ){
                    night_num.append('<option value="' + date_diff + '" >' + date_diff + '</option>')
                }
                $('#gdlr-night').val(date_diff);
            }
        });

        // amount change
        $(this).on('change', '#gdlr-room-number', function(){
            var amount = parseInt($(this).val());
            var resv_room = resv_bar.find('#gdlr-reservation-people-amount-wrapper');
            var room_diff = amount - resv_room.children().length;
            if( room_diff > 0 ){
                for( var i=0; i<room_diff; i++ ){
                    var new_room = resv_room.children(':first-child').clone().hide();
                    new_room.find('.gdlr-reservation-people-title span').html(resv_room.children().length + 1);
                    new_room.appendTo(resv_room).slideDown(200);
                }
            }else if( room_diff < 0 ){
                resv_room.children().slice(room_diff).slideUp(200, function(){
                    $(this).remove();
                });
            }
        }); 

        $(this).submit(function(){
            if( $(this).find('select[name=gdlr-hotel-branches]').val() == '' ){
                $(this).find('#please-select-branches').slideDown();
                return false;
            }
        });
    }

    $.fn.gdlr_hotel_booking = function(){

        var area = {
            wrapper: $(this),
            resv_bar: $(this).find('#gdlr-reservation-bar'),
            room_form: $(this).find('#gdlr-reservation-bar-room-form'),
            date_form: $(this).find('#gdlr-reservation-bar-date-form'),
            summary_form: $(this).find('#gdlr-reservation-bar-summary-form'),
            service_form: $(this).find('#gdlr-reservation-bar-service-form'),

            proc_bar: $(this).find('#gdlr-booking-process-bar'),
            content_area: $(this).find('#gdlr-booking-content-inner'),

        };

        var resv_bar = {
            init: function(){

                // check in date and night num change
                area.resv_bar.on('change', '#gdlr-night, #gdlr-check-in', function(){
                    var check_in = area.resv_bar.find('#gdlr-check-in');
                    var check_out = area.resv_bar.find('#gdlr-check-out');
                    var night_num = area.resv_bar.find('#gdlr-night');

                    if( check_in.val() ){
                        var check_out_date = check_in.datepicker('getDate', '+1d'); 
                        check_out_date.setDate(check_out_date.getDate() + parseInt(night_num.val()));

                        check_out.datepicker('setDate', check_out_date);

                        var check_out_min = check_in.datepicker('getDate', '+1d'); 
                        check_out_min.setDate(check_out_min.getDate() + 1);

                        $('#gdlr-datepicker-range').datepicker('refresh');

                        check_out.datepicker('option', 'minDate', check_out_min);
                    }
                });

                // check out date change
                area.resv_bar.on('change', '#gdlr-check-out', function(){
                    var check_in = area.resv_bar.find('#gdlr-check-in').datepicker('getDate');
                    var check_out = $(this).datepicker('getDate');
                    var date_diff = (check_out - check_in) / 86400000; // 1000/60/60/24

                    if( check_in && date_diff > 0 ){
                        var night_num = area.resv_bar.find('#gdlr-night');
                        if( night_num.children('option[value="' + date_diff + '"]').length == 0 ){
                            night_num.append('<option value="' + date_diff + '" >' + date_diff + '</option>')
                        }
                        $('#gdlr-night').val(date_diff);
                    }
                });

                // amount change
                area.resv_bar.on('change', '#gdlr-room-number', function(){
                    var amount = parseInt($(this).val());
                    var resv_room = area.resv_bar.find('#gdlr-reservation-people-amount-wrapper');
                    var room_diff = amount - resv_room.children().length;
                    if( room_diff > 0 ){
                        for( var i=0; i<room_diff; i++ ){
                            var new_room = resv_room.children(':first-child').clone().hide();
                            new_room.find('.gdlr-reservation-people-title span').html(resv_room.children().length + 1);
                            new_room.appendTo(resv_room).slideDown(200);
                        }
                    }else if( room_diff < 0 ){
                        resv_room.children().slice(room_diff).slideUp(200, function(){
                            $(this).remove();
                        });
                    }

                }); 

                // check availability button
                area.resv_bar.on('click', '#gdlr-reservation-bar-button', function(){
                    main.change_state({ state: 2 });
                    return false;
                });

                // query again when input change
                area.resv_bar.on('change', '#gdlr-check-in, #gdlr-night, #gdlr-check-out, #gdlr-room-number, #gdlr-hotel-branches, ' + 
                    'select[name="gdlr-adult-number[]"], select[name="gdlr-children-number[]"]', function(){

                    if( parseInt(area.proc_bar.attr('data-state')) > 1 ){
                        area.room_form.slideUp(function(){
                            $(this).html('').removeClass('gdlr-active');
                            main.change_state({ state: 2 });
                        });

                    }
                });
            }   
        }

        var proc_bar = {
            get_state: function(){
                return area.proc_bar.attr('data-state');
            },

            set_state: function( state ){
                area.proc_bar.attr('data-state', state);
                area.proc_bar.children('[data-process="' + state + '"]').addClass('gdlr-active').siblings().removeClass('gdlr-active');
            }
        }

        var main = {
            init: function(){

                // init date picker
                area.wrapper.find('.gdlr-datepicker').gdlr_datepicker(); 
                area.wrapper.find("#gdlr-datepicker-range").gdlr_datepicker_range();

                // reservation bar event
                resv_bar.init();

                // room selection event
                this.room_select();

                // contact form event
                this.contact_submit();
            },

            room_select: function(){
                area.content_area.on('click', '.price-breakdown-close', function(){
                    $(this).closest('.price-breakdown-wrapper').fadeOut(200);
                    return false;
                });
                area.content_area.on('click', '.gdlr-price-break-down', function(){
                    $(this).children('.price-breakdown-wrapper').fadeIn(200);
                });

                area.content_area.on('click', '.gdlr-room-selection',function(){
                    area.room_form.find('.gdlr-active input').val($(this).attr('data-roomid'));
                    main.change_state({ state: 2, room_id: $(this).attr('data-roomid') });
                    return false;
                });

                area.content_area.on('click', '.gdlr-pagination a', function(){
                    main.change_state({ paged: $(this).attr('data-paged'), state: 2 });
                    return false;
                });

                area.room_form.on('click', '.gdlr-reservation-change-room',function(){
                    $(this).closest('.gdlr-reservation-room').find('input').val('');
                    main.change_state({ state: 2 });
                    return false;
                });

                // edit booking summary event
                area.summary_form.on('click', '#gdlr-edit-booking-button', function(){
                    area.room_form.find('.gdlr-reservation-room:first-child input').val('');
                    main.change_state({ state: 2 });
                    return false;
                });

                area.summary_form.on('change', 'input[name="pay_deposit"]', function(){
                    if($(this).val() == 'true'){
                        area.summary_form.find('.gdlr-price-deposit-inner-wrapper').slideDown();
                        area.summary_form.find('.gdlr-price-summary-grand-total').removeClass('gdlr-active');
                        area.summary_form.find('input[name="pay_deposit"][value="true"]').closest('span').addClass('gdlr-active');
                        area.summary_form.find('input[name="pay_deposit"][value="false"]').closest('span').removeClass('gdlr-active');
                    }else{
                        area.summary_form.find('.gdlr-price-deposit-inner-wrapper').slideUp();
                        area.summary_form.find('.gdlr-price-summary-grand-total').addClass('gdlr-active');
                        area.summary_form.find('input[name="pay_deposit"][value="true"]').closest('span').removeClass('gdlr-active');
                        area.summary_form.find('input[name="pay_deposit"][value="false"]').closest('span').addClass('gdlr-active');
                    }
                    return false;
                });

            },

            contact_submit: function(){

                // for submitting service
                area.content_area.on('change', '.gdlr-room-service-checkbox input', function(){
                    if( $(this).is(":checked") ){
                        $(this).parent('label').addClass('gdlr-active').siblings('input').prop('disabled', false);
                    }else{
                        $(this).parent('label').removeClass('gdlr-active').siblings('input').prop('disabled', true);
                    }
                });
                area.content_area.on('click', '.gdlr-room-selection-next',function(){
                    main.change_state({ state: 3, service: $(this).siblings('.gdlr-booking-service-wrapper').children('form') });
                    return false;
                });

                // for submitting contact form
                area.content_area.on('click', '.gdlr-booking-contact-submit', function(){
                    if( !$(this).hasClass('gdlr-clicked') ){
                        $(this).addClass('gdlr-clicked');
                        area.content_area.find('.gdlr-error-message').slideUp();
                        main.change_state({ state: 3, contact: $(this).closest('form'), 'contact_type': 'contact' });
                    }
                    return false; 
                });

                area.content_area.on('click', '.gdlr-booking-payment-submit', function(){
                    if( !$(this).hasClass('gdlr-clicked') ){
                        $(this).addClass('gdlr-clicked');
                        area.content_area.find('.gdlr-error-message').slideUp();
                        main.change_state({ state: 3, contact: $(this).closest('form'), 'contact_type': 'instant_payment' });
                    }
                    return false; 
                });

                // payment method selection
                area.content_area.on('click', '.gdlr-payment-method input[name="payment-method"]',function(){
                    $(this).parent('label').addClass('gdlr-active').siblings().removeClass('gdlr-active');
                });
            },

            change_state: function( options ){
                if( area.resv_bar.find('select[name=gdlr-hotel-branches]').val() == '' ){
                    area.resv_bar.find('#please-select-branches').slideDown();
                    return false;
                }else{
                    area.resv_bar.find('#please-select-branches').slideUp();
                }

                area.resv_bar.find('#gdlr-reservation-bar-button').slideUp(200, function(){ $(this).remove(); })

                area.content_area.animate({'opacity': 0.2});
                area.content_area.parent().addClass('gdlr-loading');

                var data_submit = { 
                    'action': area.resv_bar.attr('data-action'),
                    'data': area.resv_bar.serialize(), 
                    'state': options.state 
                };
                if( options.room_id ) data_submit.room_id = options.room_id;
                if( options.service ){
                    data_submit.service = options.service.serialize();
                    if( !data_submit.service ){
                        data_submit.service = 'service=none';
                    }
                }
                if( options.contact ) data_submit.contact = options.contact.serialize();
                if( options.contact_type ) data_submit.contact_type = options.contact_type;
                if( options.paged ) data_submit.paged = options.paged;

                $.ajax({
                    type: 'POST',
                    url: area.wrapper.attr('data-ajax'),
                    data: data_submit,
                    dataType: 'json',
                    error: function( a, b, c ){ console.log(a, b, c); },
                    success: function( data ){
                        //console.log(data.data);

                        if( data.state ){
                            proc_bar.set_state(data.state);

                            if( data.content ){
                                var tmp_height = area.content_area.height();
                                area.content_area.html(data.content);

                                var new_height = area.content_area.height();

                                area.content_area.parent().removeClass('gdlr-loading');
                                area.content_area.height(tmp_height).animate({'opacity': 1, 'height': new_height}, function(){
                                    $(this).css('height', 'auto');
                                });
                            }
                            if( data.summary_form ){
                                if( !area.summary_form.hasClass('gdlr-active') ){
                                    area.summary_form.html(data.summary_form).slideDown().addClass('gdlr-active');
                                }else{
                                    var tmp_height = area.summary_form.height();
                                    area.summary_form.html(data.summary_form);

                                    var new_height = area.summary_form.height();
                                    area.summary_form.height(tmp_height).animate({'height': new_height}, function(){
                                        $(this).css('height', 'auto');
                                    });
                                }
                            }
                            if( data.service ){
                                area.service_form.html(data.service);
                            }

                            if( data.state == 2 ){
                                area.summary_form.slideUp(function(){ $(this).removeClass('gdlr-active'); });
                                area.date_form.slideDown();

                                if( data.room_form ){
                                    if( !area.room_form.hasClass('gdlr-active') ){
                                        area.room_form.html(data.room_form).slideDown().addClass('gdlr-active');
                                    }else{
                                        var tmp_height = area.room_form.height();
                                        area.room_form.html(data.room_form);

                                        var new_height = area.room_form.height();
                                        area.room_form.height(tmp_height).animate({'height': new_height}, function(){
                                            $(this).css('height', 'auto');
                                        });
                                    }
                                }
                            }else if( data.state == 3 ){
                                area.room_form.slideUp(function(){ $(this).removeClass('gdlr-active'); });
                                area.date_form.slideUp();

                                // error message on form submit
                                if( data.error_message ){
                                    area.content_area.find('.gdlr-button').removeClass('gdlr-clicked');
                                    area.content_area.find('.gdlr-error-message').html(data.error_message).slideDown();

                                    area.content_area.parent().removeClass('gdlr-loading');
                                    area.content_area.animate({'opacity': 1});
                                }

                                // for payment option
                                if( data.payment && data.payment == 'paypal' ){
                                    var form_submit = area.content_area.find('form.gdlr-booking-contact-form');
                                    form_submit.attr('method', 'post');
                                    form_submit.attr('action', data.payment_url);
                                    form_submit.append(data.addition_part);
                                    form_submit.submit();

                                }
                            }
                        } // data.state
                    }
                }); 
            }
        };

        main.init();

        return this;
    }

    $(document).ready(function(){

        // init the booking page
        $('#gdlr-single-booking-content').gdlr_hotel_booking();

        // init single room page
        $('body.single #gdlr-reservation-bar, #gdlr-hotel-availability').gdlr_single_booking();

        // room category hover
        $('.gdlr-room-category-item').on('mouseover', '.gdlr-room-category-thumbnail', function(){
            $(this).children('img').transition({ scale: 1.1, duration: 200, queue: false });
            $(this).children('.gdlr-room-category-thumbnail-overlay').animate({opacity: 0.6}, {duration: 150, queue: false});
            $(this).children('.gdlr-room-category-thumbnail-overlay-icon').animate({opacity: 1}, {duration: 150, queue: false});
        });
        $('.gdlr-room-category-item').on('mouseout', '.gdlr-room-category-thumbnail', function(){
            $(this).children('img').transition({ scale: 1, duration: 200, queue: false });
            $(this).children('.gdlr-room-category-thumbnail-overlay').animate({opacity: 0}, {duration: 150, queue: false});
            $(this).children('.gdlr-room-category-thumbnail-overlay-icon').animate({opacity: 0}, {duration: 150, queue: false});
        });
    });

})(jQuery);
```

Now in the php part there is:

```
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'gdlr_hotel_include_script' );
if( !function_exists('gdlr_hotel_include_script') ){
    function gdlr_hotel_include_script(){
        wp_enqueue_style('hotel-style', plugins_url('gdlr-hotel.css', __FILE__) );

        wp_enqueue_script('jquery-ui-core');
        wp_enqueue_script('jquery-ui-datepicker');
        wp_enqueue_script('hotel-script', plugins_url('gdlr-hotel.js', __FILE__), array(), '1.0.0', true );

        // ref : https://gist.github.com/clubduece/4053820
        global $wp_locale;

        $aryArgs = array(
            'closeText'         => __( 'Done', 'gdlr-hotel' ),
            'currentText'       => __( 'Today', 'gdlr-hotel' ),
            'monthNames'        => gdlr_strip_array_indices( $wp_locale->month ),
            'monthNamesShort'   => gdlr_strip_array_indices( $wp_locale->month_abbrev ),
            'monthStatus'       => __( 'Show a different month', 'gdlr-hotel' ),
            'dayNames'          => gdlr_strip_array_indices( $wp_locale->weekday ),
            'dayNamesShort'     => gdlr_strip_array_indices( $wp_locale->weekday_abbrev ),
            'dayNamesMin'       => gdlr_strip_array_indices( $wp_locale->weekday_initial ),
            'firstDay'          => get_option( 'start_of_week' )
        );

        // Pass the localized array to the enqueued JS
        wp_localize_script( 'hotel-script', 'objectL10n', $aryArgs );   
    }
}
```

Can someone help me

Thanking you in advance
Akshat

Comment: Refer [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19836936/how-to-set-3-months-date-range-in-date-picker](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19836936/how-to-set-3-months-date-range-in-date-picker)....

Comment: @KaushaMehta Sir i am not able to use the code with mine

Comment: please add this line after minDate  `maxDate: '+60D',`

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use this javascript where you had to select start date now on selected you had just add your end month on that.

You had to add OnClose function for close booking script.

```
$(this).datepicker({
            minDate: 0,
            dateFormat : gdlr_dfm,
            numberOfMonths: [1, 2],
            onClose: function (selectedDate, instance) {
                if (selectedDate != '') {
                    $("#to").datepicker("option", "minDate", selectedDate);
                    var date = $.datepicker.parseDate(instance.settings.dateFormat, selectedDate, instance.settings);
                    date.setMonth(date.getMonth() + 2);
                    console.log(selectedDate, date);
                    $("#to").datepicker("option", "minDate", selectedDate);
                    $("#to").datepicker("option", "maxDate", date);
                }
            }
            beforeShowDay: function(date) {
                var date1 = $.datepicker.parseDate(gdlr_dfm, $("#gdlr-check-in").val());
                var date2 = $.datepicker.parseDate(gdlr_dfm, $("#gdlr-check-out").val());
                return [true, date1 && ((date.getTime() == date1.getTime()) || (date2 && date >= date1 && date <= date2)) ? "dp-highlight" : ""];
            },
            onSelect: function(dateText, inst) {
                var date1 = $.datepicker.parseDate(gdlr_dfm, $("#gdlr-check-in").val());
                var date2 = $.datepicker.parseDate(gdlr_dfm, $("#gdlr-check-out").val());
                if (!date1 || date2) {
                    $("#gdlr-check-in").datepicker('setDate', dateText);
                    $("#gdlr-check-out").val('');
                } else {
                    $("#gdlr-check-out").datepicker('setDate', dateText).trigger('change');
                }
            },
            closeText: objectL10n.closeText,
            currentText: objectL10n.currentText,
            monthNames: objectL10n.monthNames,
            monthNamesShort: objectL10n.monthNamesShort,
            dayNames: objectL10n.dayNames,
            dayNamesShort: objectL10n.dayNamesShort,
            dayNamesMin: objectL10n.dayNamesMin,
            firstDay: objectL10n.firstDay
        });
```